# Accessing javascript code injected by RegisterClientScriptBlock in client javascript block of aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have a c# code like following

```
 string albertaSTR = "var alberta;";
    foreach (DataRow dr in alberta)
    {
        albertaSTR += "alberta.push('" + dr[0].ToString() + "');";


    }
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("al", "<script>"+albertaSTR+"</script>");
```

In code above I am creating and populating javascript array using RegisterClientScriptBlock method.

I want to access this array in client side javascript block, Like this

```
  for (i = 0; i < alberta.length; i++) {
                $("#divCity > ul").append("<li><a src='#' >"+alberta[i]+"</a></li>")
            }
```

How can I do this, above code in aspx file giving me error that "alberta" array not exists

Is there a way to achieve the above functionality

Answer (score 0):

You have got to declare the variable as an Array.

```
string albertaSTR = "var alberta = [];"; // declare it as an array first
foreach(DataRow dr in alberta) {
    albertaSTR += "alberta.push('" + dr[0].ToString() + "');";
}
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "al",  "<script>" +albertaSTR+"</script>");
```

Comment: no it's not working. array alberta is not written to javascript block in aspx page

Comment: it's giving error:: No overload for method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' takes 3 arguments

Comment: now giving  No overload for method 'RegisterClientScriptBlock' takes 4 arguments

Comment: @abc ah! The script tags are needed. Check it now

Comment: it's giving javascript error:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. means array alberta is not found in the script block, any other idea?